# How can I set the counter to 30 again, and stop it at 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I have a counter I use for my script that counts from 30 down, and I want that it stops at 0. Then, if I press a button I want to set it back to 30 and it should start counting down again. This is my code for now:

```
counter = 30

def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        global counter
        counter -= 1
        zähler.config(text=str(counter))
        zähler.after(1000, count)
    count()

zähler = Label(fg="black")
zähler.grid(row=0, column=0)
zähler.after(29000, jokerfragen)#Does something important for my script.

zähler.config(text="30")
counter_label(zähler)
```

Comment: there are lots of ways to do what you are asking, but many are context dependent.  As written, I can't 'say I understand the context of your code.  I don't know what the Label() function is for example.  If the answer below about using a for loop is not helpful, I think you will need to rewrite your code as a standalone script that more contextually captures your question

Comment: @VinceWest The Label Comes trom tkinter and is for the graphic

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a function, you can accomplish the exact same thing by using a `for` loop. That way the `counter` variable becomes unnecessary, and your code is easier to understand and modify. Here's an example:

```
def counter_label():
    for counter in range(30, -1, -1): # loops backwards from 30 up to and including 0
        zähler.config(text = str(counter))
        zähler.after(1000, count)
```

Whenever your button is pressed, just call `counter_label` and it will loop from 30 to 0 again.

**EDIT**

As a response to your comments, use this piece of code:

```
def counter_label():
    while True: # keeps looping forever
        for counter in range(30, -1, -1): # loops backwards from 30 up to and including 0
            zähler.config(text = str(counter))
            zähler.after(1000, count)
        sleep(1000) # waits 1000ms
```

Comment: @Florian, is the error about `counter` in this line: `zähler.after(1000, counter)`? Maybe it should have been `count` anyway (I thought this was a mistake at first). If not, could you please describe the error?

Comment: @Florian, OK, use `range(30, -1, -1)` instead.

Comment: TypeError: counter_label() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @Florian, you're still passing `label` as an argument, although this function requires none. (I removed it as it had no use.)

Comment: But i Need it as Label because it Need to be showed in a Tkinter window

Comment: @Florian, yes you need `label`, but not in this part of the code. This method doesn't use label so it's not necessary to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Count is not defined

Comment: @Florian, it could not be working because of al kinds of things, but one thing is in any case incorrect: calling `count()`, because it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: but what Needs to stay here `zähler.after(1000, count)` then?
because there is no Count? is it `Counter_label`? or `Counter?`

Comment: @Florian, I don't know what `.after(1000, count)` does. You need to explain more. Does it just fire `count` again after 1000ms?

Comment: that after 1000ms (1second) it starts again and does -1 and then again and does -1 so the 30 is going down.

Comment: Hey i'll open a new question with my Whole Python Code because i have a very crazy error now

Comment: @Florian, good idea. Please select this as the answer if the loop helped you, though.

Comment: yeah yeah i will do that
i can post the new Thing in 30 minutes first so i'll wait a Little bit for now

Comment: @Florian, if I have time I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter_label(label):
    def count():
        global counter
        counter -= 1
        counter %= 30
        zähler.config(text=str(counter))
        zähler.after(1000, count)
    count()
```

By doing `counter %= 30`, you can reset the counter back to 29 once it reaches -1 which is the same as what you already have